# Team Calendar Group Permissions

Tags: exchange-2010, calendar

I have a manager who deleted automatically generated team calendar group, now I would like to regenerate that and set permissions to the actual group, not individual calendars, so that it cannot be deleted again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid can not achieve your needs. The user deletes the entire calendar group in his/her mailbox using the management permissions of the mailbox, instead of the permission on the calendar group, so, whatever you set permissions to the group or not, if the user does not want to see this calendar group in his/her mailbox, he/she can delete the entire group directly.